# I can click a button in Firefox - why not in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir WebDriver with Chrome and Firefox.

With FF, I can click the following button:

```
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').when_present.click
```

With Chrome, I get the following message:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (730, 681). Other element would receive the click: <div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.38143215011627357; cursor: default; position: fixed;"></div>
```

If I place a breakpoint on the offending line, the next single step in debug mode works OK.

As an experiment, in case of timeout issues, I changed the code to:

```
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').when_present(100).click
```

This fails in run mode, with the same error.

If I search the entire page, I can't find the "other element" that would receive the click.

```
<div class="blockUI.............
```

Here are the divs before and after the button:

```
<div id="divSaveCancel" class="row">
    <div class="six mobile-four columns">
        <ul class="button-group even three-up">
            <li>
                <button id="cancelBtn" type="button" class="small alert button">
                    Cancel</button></li>
            <li>
                <button class="small button" id="btnSave" type="submit" name="command" value="btnSaveDraft"
                    onclick="beforeSubmit();">
                    Save Draft</button></li>
            <li>
                <button class="small success button" id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="command"
                    onclick="beforeSubmit();" value="btnSubmit">
                    Save and Continue</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="six mobile-four columns" style="text-align: right;">
        <span style="text-align: right; margin-right: 5%; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">
            <button id="btnSendNotification2" class="small button" type="button">
                Send Notification</button></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you were looking for the overlay div, did you check the actual DOM (eg using the browser's developer toolbar) or did you view the page source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
while (@browser.div(:class => 'blockUI blockOverlay').present?)
  sleep(1)
end
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').click
```

You should be able to do:

```
@browser.div(:class => 'blockUI blockOverlay').wait_while_present
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').click
```

Answer (score 0):

@JustinKo: I checked both.

Here is a comment from the developer:

> It is a modal ‘Please Wait...’ popup that appears for a very short duration of time when the document is being loaded or when some time consuming activity is being performed. That code is dynamically injected by JQuery plug-in and removed soon after. That may be the reason why we can’t find it in the document source.

Remember that the following did not work:

```
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').when_present(100).click
```

But the following works:

```
sleep(1)
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').click
```

So the target element is always present.

The following does not work:

```
while !(@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').visible?)
  sleep(1)
end
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').click
```

So the target element is always visible.

The solution is to wait for the "other element" to disappear:

```
while (@browser.div(:class => 'blockUI blockOverlay').present?)
  sleep(1)
end
@browser.button(:id => 'btnSubmit').click
```